Ubuntu Server installer fails on MacMini mid 2011
im trying to install Ubuntu Server 24.04.1 LTS on my MacMini 2011 5,1. I am able to get to the screen where you set up the password and user and stuff, but after around 10 Seconds i always get the error message "Sorry, there was an error completing the installation". I have tried to install it from other USB Sticks, on different hard drives or SSDs, tried the minimal installation, but no matter what i do it always fails at the same step. I have also tried installing the normal Ubuntu Desktop LTS, and i got it running afer battling with the Installer for some time, but i really need Ubuntu Server. I think that the Installer of Ubuntu Server has the same Problem as the one for Ubuntu Desktop, but since the Desktop Installer is Graphical i was somehow able to get it to work, but i cant on the Server installer since im not that good with Terminals and stuff (yet). Im pretty desprate bc i just want to install some basic things like Homebridge or Scrypted when i have Ubuntu running, but i cant even install the operating System and i already tried everything that i found on the Internet but nothing worked nor did Google so u guys are my last resort. Thanks in advance.
